# Check If user input begins with either of 2 possibilities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a page where a customer will input certain data, However, in one of the fields, the Input should only begin with either 'SWG...' *or* 'MH...'. On top of this, the SWG should contain 7 numbers after, and MH should contain 5.

I am quite new to this so any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is Below.

```
public partial class VehicleRegistration
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User Email:")]
    public string User_Email { get; set; }


    [Required] //This is the section where input should only begin with MH or SWG
    [Display(Name = "Serial No:")] 
    public string Serial_No { get; set; }

    [Required] 
    [StringLength(16, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 16)]
    [Display(Name = "Control Panel M Number:")]
    public string IMEI_No { get; set; }

 }
```

The Last field here is what i have for setting how long input should be.
I also have a cshtml page with the following code which relates

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Serial_No, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Serial_No, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Required" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Serial_No, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like wpf to me, please add the "wpf" tag in future.

Comment: This doesn't looks like wpf to me, please do not add "wpf" tag in the future. Add some other tag. Thanks.

Comment: @Rariolu It's from an MVC project.

Comment: My apologies. But still, tags are useful.

Comment: @Rariolu My Apologies, as you can see I am new to this. Pointers in the right direction are Appreciated. I have tagged the Code now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for a system called [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), or Regex.

In your case, the solution would be

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(myText, @"^SWG\d{7}$|^MH\d{5}$"))
{
    //myText is valid
}
```

In MVC, the field would look like

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^SWG\d{7}$|^MH\d{5}$", ErrorMessage="Serial number must be SWG####### or MH#####")]
[Display(Name = "Serial No:")] 
public string Serial_No { get; set; }
```

You can see a breakdown of how the regex works [here](https://regex101.com/r/rV0oB0/1).

Comment: It's `Regex` not `RegEx` and  you either need to delimit those backslashes or make the pattern a verbatim string by putting a @ before it.  And you should be calling `IsMatch` if you want a `bool` instead of `Matches`.  And finally the pattern is the second argument.

Comment: @juharr I fixed the mistakes (too many languages washing around in my brain), but the groupings are not required, in .net at least (I tested).  I also added `^` and `$`, when I noticed `MH1234567` would match.

Comment: @RoadieRich Thank you very much, this works perfectly. I learnt something new.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a regex validation in MVC like this:

```
[RegularExpression("SWG\d{7}|MH\d{5}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid input")]
[Required] //This is the section where input should only begin with MH or SWG
[Display(Name = "Serial No:")] 
public string Serial_No { get; set; }
```

However, if you need more complex validation logic, try learning more about **Remote** validation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(VS.98).aspx).